# Mirabox Capture Card and External Power Source

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, alternative-power

I'm looking to power my Raspberry Pi 4B from a 12V tractor battery. I have a buck converter which can be [found here](https://www.amazon.ca/Yeeco-Converter-1-25-36V-Regulator-Transformer/dp/B06X6BTRBK/ref=pd_di_sccai_1/131-3206943-2378909?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B06X6BTRBK&pd_rd_r=37ba0b92-2851-4b15-ae48-b9b354e826df&pd_rd_w=NXZgO&pd_rd_wg=nz63c&pf_rd_p=a5f9e780-487d-4881-a2b8-b9a00c4b0707&pf_rd_r=HE4C2H05SQ329CKQAJKM&psc=1&refRID=HE4C2H05SQ329CKQAJKM#customerReviews). I am considering using this device to step-down the battery voltage and hook up the output of the converter to the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi. The other option I am considering is to to use this USB-c step down converter [found here](https://www.amazon.ca/HOMREE-Step-Down-Converter-Module-Charger/dp/B07ZQB6S3L/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=DC-DC+12V+to+5V+3A+USB-C+Converter&qid=1594387510&s=electronics&sr=1-2). I know the usb-c connector on the Pi is safer because of onboard regulators/fuses. My only concern is that this converter is only rated for 15W(5V 3A). Will that be sufficient? Important Info- I plan on connecting a Mirabox capture card to the USB-c port. [See here](https://www.amazon.ca/Mirabox-Capture-30FPS-USB3-0-Passthrough/dp/B07MGPVX83#:%7E:text=%20Mirabox%20Capture%20Card%2C%204K%2030FPS%2CHD%201080P%2060FPS%2CUSB3.0,3.5mm%20Microphone%20and%20Audio%20Input%20Port%2C...%20More%20). It will thus be powered by the Pi. Accordingly, I am afraid of current spikes(etc). Any advice is appreciated. Hopefully, my post is clear.

Would it be possible to open up a USB-c cable and connect the VCC and GRD to the output Terminals of the Buck Converter and ignore the Data+ and Data- cords? My reasoning is that the USB-c normally just recieving DC current anyway. I don't believe the Pi would receive serial communication from the outlet(AC/DC adapter/transformer).

Comment: I haven't cut a USB-C so I can't say for sure, but I've done it with USB 2/3.0 cables -- in fact some of them don't even have the data lines, if they are sold specifically as *power* cables.

Comment: Hmm: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/310533/52138

Answer (score 0):

"I know the usb-c connector on the Pi is safer because of onboard regulators/fuses" then you know wrong!
The Pi4 has **NO fuses** and the regulator is used to supply lower voltages derived from the 5V input. There is no 5V regulator.

Indeed **the USB-C 5V is directly connected to the 5V pins** on the expansion header, so there is no need to (or benefit from) butchering a cable.

Incidentally the USB-C connector **DOES NOT** have USB-C (or USB3) capabilities. The schematic states "USB-C (USB2 ONLY)". It is intended for POWER, although there are 2 data lines connected to the SOC (and the Power Sense pins are used), giving it USB2 OTG functionality.

You would be better using the USB3 connector.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just to be clear, this USB-C converter will provide enough power for my Raspberry Pi? Should I add anything else to the circuit in order to protect my board?